# Disk full on a server with a large /home partition

Tags: linux, centos, partition, disk-usage

I've just got this CentOS Server but I think I've set it up wrong as I can only upload a few GB then I start getting errors, It should have ~1TB.

this is the results of lsblk

```
[root@ns4005990 ~]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  19.5G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0 911.5G  0 part /home
└─sda3   8:3    0   511M  0 part [SWAP]
```

I'm guessing its using sda1 as the main storage but should be using sda 2?

I know very little about linux, Any ideas how i can fix it so its using sda2?

```
[root@ns4005990 ~]# df -h /home
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       905G  200M  859G   1% /home
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I just can't upload anymore files, and it says sda1 has used all its space.

Comment: paste the output of `df -h /home`

Comment: Have updated with that command, I just keep getting these errors when trying to upload, I get a few files uploaded then it gives this error: `Error: File transfer failed after transferring 185,344 bytes in 1 second`

Comment: As you can see, it's not a matter of partition full. Check the logs (/var/log/messages might be a good way to start). Also, waht command are you using to upload files?

Comment: Are you uploading data from another machine? Which machine is printing the message? Paste output of `df -h` to question, and add info about which application is performing the transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two filesystem partitions, one mounted on `/` (the root partition, `sda1`) containing your operating system and one mounted on `/home` (the home partition, `sda2`) containing your personal files. Your home partition is nowhere near full, so it must be your root partition that's full.

On a workstation, large files typically end up in users' home directories. On a server, `/home` typically remains small: the bulk of the data is usually under `/var` or `/srv`, depending on how your services are set up.

Run `du -xh / | grep G` (or, to avoid spurious hits if a file name contains `G`: `du -xh / | grep '^[0-9.]*G'`) to see which directories on the root partition contain a lot of data. Move the one that's getting filled up to `/home`. Let's say that the large amount of data ends up somewhere under `/srv`, then:

1. Stop all services that are accessing data under `/srv`.
2. Run the following commands:

   ```
   mv /srv /home/
   ln -s home/srv /
   ```
3. Restart all services.

This makes `/srv` a symbolic link pointing to a directory on the home partition.

Comment: `du -xh / | grep -E '^[0-9]+G'`

Comment: @DanGarthwaite `du -xh / | grep -E '^[0-9.]+G'`, actually. I hesitated but went for simple to type over precise.

Comment: I do that all the time, too.  Just sharing for future googlers that I vetted that `du -xh / | grep -E '^[0-9]+G'` works.

Comment: @DanGarthwaite No, I insist, you need the `.`: for sizes between 1 and 10 units, GNU `du` can print a number like `4.2G`.

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  Twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading files to somewhere on the root partition, for sure.  Are you uploading to/as user root?  User root's home is special and not located on the /home partition.

I hunt down out-of-disk-space errors all the time.

As root run the following and post it for us:

```
for dir in var usr root; do echo /$dir/; du -sm /$dir/* | sort -n| tail -5; done
```

This will narrow it down. Then, say it is /var/log that seems huge:

```
cd /var/log; du -smc * | sort -n | tail
```

Repeat `du -smc * | sort -n | tail` in each offensively large subdirectory until you find the culprit.